# use dcolumn with the same font as the rest of text and bold

Tags: tables, bold, dcolumn

I have been searching the web for the past hours and cannot find an answer to this question.

I have stumbled upon:
1. `\newcolumntype{T}[3]{>{\textfont0=\the\font\DC@{#1}{#2}{#3}}c<{\DC@end}}`

which allows me to use dcolumn with the same font type as the rest of the text and

2. `\newcolumntype{B}[3]{>{\boldmath\DC@{#1}{#2}{#3}}c<{\DC@end}}`

which puts the text of a certain cell in bold.

What I am looking for is to combine both 1 and 2, resulting in some sort of macro that allows me to use boldface of text font in some cells.

Thank you and best regards !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What you are trying to achieve *can* be done with the machinery of the `dcolumn` package. That said, it would be *considerably easier* to achieve by loading the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type. Please post some example code that you'd like to format in a certain way.

Comment: thank you Mico. But could you please help me achieving this using dcolumn? Consider a column "x.yz", whose contents are already aligned by decimal point using \newcolumntype{T} descbribed above. Now i want to set a number in that column to bold, maintaining the textfont.

Answer (score 2):

```
\newcolumntype{Z}[3]{>{\bfseries\textfont0=\the\font\DC@{#1}{#2}{#3}}c<{\DC@end}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input David. But I am getting an "undefined control sequence }" error. This is what I am writing: \multicolumn{1}{Z{.}{.}{-1}}{3.21}

Comment: @Peter which command is shown as undefined? The only command I added was `\bfseries` which is defined in the latex format.

Comment: David ! my bad, i was entering the command after "\makeatother". Thanks a lot for the quick reply. you're the man.